# Why does my multipart form-data get converted to JSON?

Tags: android, json, jackson, android-annotations

I need to do a POST towards an API where multipart form-data is required with one record where the key 'json' and the value is a string containing a json object.

I'm trying to do it using AndroidAnnotations like this:

```
@Post(API_CREATE_PATH + API_KEY)
CreateResponse create(Map<String,String> map);
```

A valid request looks like the following, done with Postman:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"

{"test":"data"}
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

Instead of that, the actual request body contains `"json":"{"test":"data"}"`, and I can't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a multi-part POST in this way, as [explained in the wiki](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest%20API#post).

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "http://company.com/ajax/services", converters = FormHttpMessageConverter.class)
public interface MyRestClient extends RestClientHeaders {

  @Post(API_CREATE_PATH + API_KEY)
  @RequiresHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE)
  CreateResponse create(MultiValueMap<String,Object> map);
}

MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.set("test","data");

client.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE);

client.create(map);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked indeed. My guess is that the `@RequiresHeader` annotation was the necessary missing line in my code, because I did already call `client.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE);` before sending the request

Comment: Yeah, without that annotation the set header is not added to the request. We know this is inconvenient, this whole thing will be improved in AA 4.0, which is about to be released. :)